# Use defined value in output name in r

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have defined MV1 below with a value, and have used the MV1 in the output name. However, when I run the summary function on my model output I get the following meesage

```
'Error: unexpected symbol in: "assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') <- model1 summary" '
```

MVx is a value that is defined as a numeric in my code already, and MV1 equates to "_3" in my code.

```
MV = MVx+1
MV1= paste("_", MV, sep="")
assign(paste("Model", MV1, sep = '') = model1 <- glm(tv1~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=train70)  
summary(Model_3)     #Error occurs here
```

Would anyone know how to get around that?

Comment: The answer to your question is `assign`. However, that just means that your whole approach to whatever you actually want to achieve is probably flawed. You shouldn't need `assign` (outside some specific contexts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
MV = MVx+1
MV1= paste("_", MV, sep="")

model1 <- paste('Model', MV1, sep="")
```

Comment: If you want to assign values in reverse way, you can try like this               paste('Model', MV1, sep="") -> model1